# WS Soap Handler class never invoked

Tags: java, web-services, soap, handler, apache-axis

I am developing a Jax Ws and i want to add Soap Handler to use for WS authentication. A added a handler chain xml and a Soap Handler class but code never call the Soap Handler's method.I use JDK 8 and Tomcat 7. What can be the problem?
 My handler chain xml as below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE javaee:handler-chains>
<javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler>
            <javaee:handler-class>com.vw.AuthHandler
            </javaee:handler-class>
        </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

My Soap Handler class a below:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class AuthHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

       private static PrintStream out = System.out;  
       @Override
       public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
          return Collections.emptySet();
       }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {  
         Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);         
              if (!outboundProperty) {              
                        System.out.println("Hello!");
                    return true;   
              }
              return false;
    }
        @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

    }

}
```

My Service is as below:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import services.LoginOps;

import utilies.LoginParameters;



@WebService
@HandlerChain (file = "handlers.xml")
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT,use=SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,parameterStyle=SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)

public class LService {
    @WebMethod
    public LoginParameters callStr(String str
    }
...
```

Comment: Where did you put your **handlers.xml** in source tree?

Comment: handlers.xml, Soap Handler class and service class are in the same package. Package is com.vw